# Return day of the week of 2016 using python

Tags: python

```
def solution(a, b):
        # date
    date_31 = 31
    date_30 = 30
    date_29_yun = 29

    # day of the week(요일)
    d_o_w = ['THU','FRI','SAT','SUN','MON','TUE','WED']

    cnt_date = 0
    
    #     7로 나눠서 나머지를 요일의 인덱스로 잡는 아이디어
    # 1/2분기로 계산하는 아이디어
    if a <= 2:
        if a == 1:
#             b가 날짜 초과되는 예외 처리
            if b > 31:
                return 0
            else:
                return (d_o_w[b % len(d_o_w)])
        elif a == 2:
#             2월의 날짜 초과되는 예외처리
            if b > 29:
                return 0
            else:
                return (d_o_w[(date_31+b)%len(d_o_w)])  

    elif 8> a > 2:
        default_date = date_31 + date_29_yun
        n_31 = 0
        n_30 = 0

        if a == 3:
#           b가 날짜 초과되는 예외 처리
            if b > 31:
                return 0
            else:
                return (d_o_w[(default_date + b)%len(d_o_w)])
#         b의 예외적 상황 처리
        if a%2 == 0:
            if b > 30:
                return 0
        else:
            if b > 31:
                return 0
        
        for i in range(1, a-2):
    #           31이랑 30이랑 번갈아가면서 카운팅해서 더하기
            if i%2 == 0:
                n_30 += 1
            else:
                n_31 += 1   #1부터 시작할때 이게 먼저 더해짐
    
        return (d_o_w[(default_date + date_31*n_31 + date_30*n_30 + b)%len(d_o_w)])


    elif 12 >= a > 8:
        default_date = date_31*4 + date_29_yun + date_30*2
        n_even = 0
        n_odd = 0
        if a == 8:
#           b 예외적 처리
            if b >31:
                return 0
            else:
                return (d_o_w[(default_date + b)%len(d_o_w)])

#       b 예외적 처리
        if a % 2 == 0:
            if b > 31:
                return 0
        
        else:
            if b > 30:
                return 0
            
            
        for i in range(1, a-6):
    #           31이랑 30이랑 번갈아가면서 카운팅해서 더하기
            if i%2 == 0:
                n_even += 1
            else:
                n_odd += 1   #1부터 시작할때 이게 먼저 더해짐

        return (d_o_w[(default_date + date_31*n_odd + date_30*n_even + b)%len(d_o_w)])
```

In this case, I am confient of this code. But coding test site said this code is incorrect some cases.

So, I tried limit date to solve exceeding date error not fitting month to solve exceptional case.

But some case does not work. I don't know this 'some case'. It know only coding test site.

So I guess that it might exist additional exceptional case.

But I can't search my error. How can I get over this case?

The problem link is here!
https://school.programmers.co.kr/learn/courses/30/lessons/12901

Comment: Python has calendar and datetime modules. Or is the use of these not allowed?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing, code-debugging, or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what specific problem you need help with.  See: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `calendar` module is allowed then you can use this:

```py
from calendar import weekday

def get_day(a, b):
    return ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'][weekday(2016, a, b)]

print(get_day(5, 24))  # TUE
print(get_day(3, 20))  # SUN
print(get_day(10, 31)) # MON
```

---

You can also use the `datetime` module to a similar effect:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def get_day(a, b):
    return ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'][datetime(2016, a, b).weekday()]

print(get_day(5, 24))  # TUE
print(get_day(3, 20))  # SUN
print(get_day(10, 31)) # MON
```

---

Or, without any modules installed:

```py
def get_day(a, b):
    p = 1
    q = 1
    w = 4
    d = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    while p <= a:
        w = (w + 1) % 7
        q += 1
        if p == a and q > b:
            break
        if q > d[p - 1]:
            q = 1
            p += 1
    return ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'][w - 1]

print(get_day(5, 24))  # TUE
print(get_day(3, 20))  # SUN
print(get_day(10, 31)) # MON
```

Comment: Unfortunately when you try and run these code samples on the coding test site they fail.

Comment: The first two or the last one?

Comment: Both code samples failed. Running either code generates a message: `틀렸습니다!` which translates as `"Wrong!"`